# target column should be created before or after outlier and skewness management

Tags: python, analytics

I have a confusion that is bugging me, suppose we have a data set where we need to derive the target column from the dataset

there are also some outliers and skewness in the data, should i create the target column before outlier and skewness treatment or after

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So target column should be created before you do any treatment for an outlier and skewness. It is always good to see the relationship between the target variable and IDVs that have outlier/ skewness and then decide on the treatment.
The bivariate analysis will make it clear if at all any treatment is required

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).